# 'Could not find method generalImplementation() for arguments [com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:17.0.2] '

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I tried to run react-native run-android on a project made by a developer (who I do not have contact anymore), but the build fails with the following output:

When i check my android studio graddle build it has the same error.
 How can i fix it?

By the way that problem would occur when i am using react-native-camera on windows

you can see error when clicked the link.

https://i.udemycdn.com/redactor/raw/2019-05-15_13-37-20-e3157e54d193712a8490760e2c92ca83.png